# How to generate Swagger 2.0 Json from any custom input?

Tags: swagger

I am looking for generating swagger 2.0 json from my custom json api metadata.

I have noticed this can be achieved when the input is JAX-RS or Spring, ( [Swagger Maven Plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin) ). But I want to derive swagger json from my custom JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this for the [BBC's Nitro API](https://github.com/Mermade/bbcparse/blob/master/parseNitroApi.js) I used a combination of creating the unchanging Swagger boilerplate as a string which I converted to a JSON object using JSON.parse(), and then simply iterating through the source API spec JSON object attaching various properties to the Swagger object. See the initSwagger() function and the way properties are added to the swagger object in the linked example.

Then I serialise the Swagger object with JSON.stringify() to save the Swagger document in JSON format.

An alternative would be to use a transform such as JSONT or a number of regexes to convert your source API JSON to the Swagger object, depending on how closely your source specification maps to the Swagger way of doing things.